# Inconsistency when defining friend operators of template class

Tags: templates, c++17, friend

Here is a MRE example involving two friend operators: `operator<<` and `operator-`:

```cpp
#include <ostream>

template <typename T>
class container;
template <typename T>
std::ostream operator<<(std::ostream & os, const container<T> & data);
template <typename T>
container<T> operator-(const int & first, const container<T> & second);

template <typename T>
class container
{
    public:
        container<T> operator-(const container<T> & other);
        friend std::ostream operator<< <>(std::ostream & os, const container<T> & data); // this one works
        friend container<T> operator- <>(const int & first, const container<T> & second); // error: declaration of 'operator-' as non-function
};
```

The actual definitions of the operators aren't here (and aren't relevant). As the comments show, `operator<<` compiles but `operator-` results in:

g++:

```
<source>:16:29: error: declaration of 'operator-' as non-function
   16 |         friend container<T> operator- <>(const int & first, const container<T> & second); // error: declaration of 'operator-' as non-function
      |                             ^~~~~~~~
<source>:16:37: error: expected ';' at end of member declaration
   16 |         friend container<T> operator- <>(const int & first, const container<T> & second); // error: declaration of 'operator-' as non-function
      |                                     ^
      |                                      ;
<source>:16:39: error: expected unqualified-id before '<' token
   16 |         friend container<T> operator- <>(const int & first, const container<T> & second); // error: declaration of 'operator-' as non-function
      |                                       ^
```

clang++:

```
<source>:16:29: error: friends can only be classes or functions
        friend container<T> operator- <>(const int & first, const container<T> & second); // error: declaration of 'operator-' as non-function
                            ^
<source>:16:38: error: expected ';' at end of declaration list
        friend container<T> operator- <>(const int & first, const container<T> & second); // error: declaration of 'operator-' as non-function
                                     ^
                                     ;
2 errors generated.
```

The fact that a (non friend) `operator-` has already been declared makes the friend `operator-` a "non-function".

Why does `operator<<` work and `operator-` doesn't? How can I fix `operator-`? Is a extra template parameter (not `T`) needed for the friend `operator-`?

## Edit

The problem is heavily related to [c++17](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17). It apparently compiles fine on [c++20](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b20).

Comment: Is this really an MRE? I don't get errors until I instantiate the template. And Clang doesn't give me any errors even then, only GCC does.

Comment: I think this might be a grammar issue that has since been fixed.  The code compiles with the latest GCC and Clang when compiling with C++20 mode but fails in C++17 mode.  https://godbolt.org/z/sT3n98PrG

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I get errors immediately: https://godbolt.org/z/d9xaP4PhE

Comment: Ah, I was testing with `-std=c++20`.

Comment: with latest clang and gcc version it compiles with c++20. https://godbolt.org/z/4GErs18E7

Comment: I have edited the question to include the fact that the issue is fixed in C++20. I am interested in a solution that would work in C++17.

Comment: One more thing to note with C++17 compiler only `-` operator does not work but for `+ * /` it works. https://godbolt.org/z/drK55fhq5

Comment: @foragerDev I'm getting the same error for `operator+`, can you post your code?

Comment: you are all wrong. Just change the order in which you declared operators. Compiles fine: [https://godbolt.org/z/zx8TqMfae](https://godbolt.org/z/zx8TqMfae) c++11 - c++20

Comment: Apparently gcc thinks the member operator- shadows the global operator- for the purpose of determining which template the fried operator- specialises, and clang does not. I cannot find anything in the standard about it. [mre](https://godbolt.org/z/WjnvEcGE8) But it doesn't matter because you probably should not specialise function templates anyway. Use overloading instead.

Comment: erratum: the last sentence of the previous commend does not apply, you have an instantiation, not a specialisation.

Answer (score 2):

I think you declared it in an incorrect way.

Try to do it this way:

```
template <typename T>
class container;

template <typename T>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream & os, const container<T> & data) { return os; }

template <typename T>
container<T> operator-(const int & first, const container<T> & second) {return second;}

template <typename T>
class container
{
    public:
        container<T> operator-(const container<T> & other);

        template <typename>
        friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream & os, const container<T> & data);
        
        template <typename>
        friend container<T> operator- (const int & first, const container<T> & second);
};
```

Live demo: [godbolt.org/z/Tbz1Yvf5T](https://godbolt.org/z/Tbz1Yvf5T)

**Edit**:
I have noticed that if you change the order (friend operators first). It compiles fine. `c++11` to `c++20`

```
template <typename T>
class container;

template <typename T>
std::ostream operator<<(std::ostream & os, const container<T> & data);

template <typename T>
container<T> operator-(const int & first, const container<T> & second);

template <typename T>
class container
{
    public:
        friend std::ostream operator<< <>(std::ostream & os, const container<T> & data); // this one works
        friend container<T> operator- <>(const int & first, const container<T> & second); // error: declaration of 'operator-' as non-function

        // now it compiles
        container<T> operator-(const container<T> & other);
};
```

Comment: Why are you using `template <typename>`? I was following https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/friend (section "Template friend operators"). I believe `operator<<` is defined correctly (like in cppreference).

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the code. The code of the OP compiles well with latest version of clang and gcc compilers. Might be some compiler grammar issue.

Comment: @user13840624 because that indicates that you actually declare the template friend function.

Comment: @foragerDev I don't think that this is correct. And I don't think this is heavily related to c++17. And I don't believe that writing code that requires a higher lang standard to compile is good code. I provided the example which compiles in c++11, c++14, c++17, and c++20. Whereas OP compiles only in c++20. It speaks for itself.

Comment: Why does swapping the `operator-()`es work?

Comment: Your first example declares the main template as a friend, while OP declares a specialisation as a friend. Two entirely different things.

Comment: @user13840624 because after swapping the member no longer shadows the outer function.

Comment: Sorry, an instantiation, not a specialisation.